# Java stream : turn List<T> into List<List<T>>

Tags: lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

Let's I have a class `T` with three properties : `value, position, order` : (value,position,order)

I have `List<T> input = [(1,1,1), (1,2,2), (1,3,1), (3,2,3), (5,1,2), (3,2,1)]`

Basically I would like to separate elements from previous list considering their `order` (last property) and sort each element in nested list by `position`.

So something like this :

```
List<List<T>> output = [
[(1,1,1), (3,2,1) (1,3,1)],
[(5,1,2), (1,2,2)],
[(3,2,3)]
]
```

Is it possible to do with with Stream API ?

Comment: What is this `(1,1,1)` object?

Comment: "(1,1,1)" is the same as "new T(1,1,1)"

Comment: first group by _order_ then sort by _position_ `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyTemplate::getOrder,LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
 l -> l.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTemplate::getPosition)).collect(Collectors.toList())))).values();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gropuingBy` and `collectionAndThen` collectors:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyTemplate::getOrder,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    l -> {
                        l.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTemplate::getPosition));
                        return l;
                    })
    )).values();
```

Comment: No need to create an underlying stream from a list, then sort and then collect to a new list, it could be better to just sort the list itself:
`Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), l -> { l.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTemplate::getPosition)); return l;})`

Comment: @dajavax, you are right. thanks for your good point.